# My CSS horizontal menu displays:block perfectly, but looks completely different in the subdirectory

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, css, blogengine.net

I have just implemented VS 2010's basic horizontal menu that comes when you start a new website.  Pages look fine in my root.

When I instituted a /blog/ application (blogengine.net), I made some changes ... put my own logo there, favicon, etc., and attempted to put my menu in there.  It doesn't appear to be conflicting with any other menu classes in any other stylesheet.  I even renamed the class to topmenu in the code and in the stylesheet to make sure.  And strangely, it looks fine in VS in design mode.

So I triple checked to see that no .css conflicts, so the code still look like this:

```
            <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
            <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false"
                IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="http://rtn.org/Default.aspx" Text="Home" />
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="http://rtn.org/About.aspx" Text="About RTN" />
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="http://rtn.org/resources.aspx" Text="RTN Resources" />
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="http://rtn.org/advertise.aspx" Text="Advertise with RTN" />
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="http://rtn.org/donate.aspx" Text="Donate to RTN" />
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
        </div>
```

And the CSS looks like this:

```
div.hideSkiplink
{
background-color: #3a4f63;
width: 100%;
}

div.menu
{
padding: 4px 0px 4px 8px;
}

div.menu ul
{
list-style: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: auto;
}

div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
{
background-color: #465c71;
border: 1px #4e667d solid;
color: #dde4ec;
display: block;
line-height: 1.35em;
padding: 4px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
white-space: nowrap;
}

div.menu ul li a:hover
{
background-color: #bfcbd6;
color: #465c71;
text-decoration: none;
}

div.menu ul li a:active
{
background-color: #465c71;
color: #cfdbe6;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

But as you'll see by this picture, for some reason, the display:block just isn't working for whatever reason in my /blog/ subdirectory master page as it is in my root master page:

[image: Menus]

Does anybody have an idea why this is the case?  Again, it looks good in VS in design mode.  It's just when I upload it, display:block doesn't work properly.  I've fiddled with it for hours, but can't reproduce the menu, as it should be, in my /blog/ subdirectory.  Any suggestions would be truly appreciated!

Comment: To me it looks like the CSS file doesn't load properly. Check the paths. What browser are you using? Most browser offer developer tools where you can check whether all files were loaded or not.

Comment: Hi Alex.  I've checked the paths.  I've tried in IE, Chrome, FF, and Safari, and all are doing the same thing.  And when I firebug it, it shows the CSS.  In my root, I have styles/site.css.  In my /blog/themes/Standard/ directory, I have style-min.css ... which I merged with site.css.  Everything looks fine except for the display:block option on the menu.  Thanks for your time in trying to help me figure this out!

Comment: No, it's not just `display:block;`. It looks like the whole CSS you posted is missing. Is your website available on the Internet?

Comment: Hi Alex.  Well, it's not my website; I just made it for a friend, and I just included the menu part of the CSS.  But the URL is http://realtruthnow.org ... I just came up with a temporary fix, but I wish I could make it look exactly the same!  Thanks for reading my question!

Answer (score 1):

Almost always this happens because you have relative links to your CSS that aren't linking to the correct places.  On your other pages, the stylesheets are displaying correctly because the relative link is to your correct site root.  However, on your subdomain, the root is most likely **to that subdomain** and not to the actual root of your site.

So for instance, if your link is normally:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">
```

the link is pointing to http://yoursite.com/foo/css/style.css.

However, when you're linking from your blog, even though the relative link is the same, it is now linking to http://yoursite.com/blog/foo/css/style.css.

To fix it, try putting in absolute links to make sure that this is the problem:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yoursite.com/blog/foo/css/style.css">
```

If it works after trying that, go back and make sure those relative links go to the right place and that you're being specific enough.

Comment: Hi m0ose89 ... thanks for taking the time to respond.  Yes, the pages in my root are all linked to styles/site.css.  The /blog/ pages are linked to /blog/themes/Standard/style-min.css, where I merged site.css and style-min.css together.  There was another menu in style-min.css, but I just renamed that to menu1 in the css file and site.master.  So maybe I just didn't merge it properly.  I also put in the absolute path to the style-min.css, but that didn't change anything.  Thank you for taking the time to read my question and attempt to help!  I'll keep trying!